# Team Explorer's "Compare With Unmodified Version" is disabled

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I'm using VS2010 professional with TFS; in the Team Explorer window, when I right-click and say check-in changes, I see a list of my changes; for some reason, when I right-click and choose `Compare` > `With Unmodified Version` is disabled (greyed out).

This is NOT for a new file; the `Change` type is `Edit`, so it should theoretically work.

What am I missing? Why can't I do the comparison?

Comment: Do you have a valid connection to the TFS Server?

Comment: Yes. I even have a project checked out with changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is used when you are comparing files inside of a shelveset.

If you go to File -> Shelveset -> Unshelve Pending Changes and select one of the shelvesets and then push the Details button you will see in the compare menu that the option "Compare With Unmodified Version" exists on files marked as "edit"

Comment: Why do I always have to do this for all my changes? I never manually specified that I want to use shelving.

Comment: I am saying that option is specific to a shelving scenario. After you have already checked out the file for edit- you will want to compare to either your Workspace or Latest Version. Your workspace version will be the unmodified version. Latest Version is the latest version on the TFS server.  In other words, "Workspace Version" does what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: That's strange, I used to get "no changes" when I tried that. Must've been a glitch.

Comment: Yeah give it a shot again I think you will see it is doing what you are wanting here.